# displaying array with map turn multiple in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data in another file like this

```
export const picker = [
  {
    gender: 'Male',
    region: ['France', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Korea', 'Russia'],
  },
  {
    gender: 'Female',
    region: ['France', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Korea', 'Russia'],
  },
];
```

I imported it in my parent component and I want to use the data 2 hierarchy down child component which looks something like this

```
<Child1 picker={picker}/>
```

and then passing it again to another child component inside Child1 component

```
<Child2 picker={picker} />
```

I want to create a tab to display the region

```
render() {
  const { picker } = this.props;
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Tabs>
          //display the region
          {picker.map(item => {
            return item.region.map(subitem => {
              return <Tab label={subitem} />;
            });
          })}
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

it displayed like this:

```
 France      Germany     Italy      Korea      Russia        France
```

It supposed to display without France at the end so the end will be Russia, and when I try to console.log the subitem I got multiple subitems if I try to console.log the item I got  objects when I should just get 2 objects

Comment: try assigning picker like this const picker = this.props.picker.  You assigned the whole props object(im not sure I get the problem maybe more code?)

Comment: @radlaz `const { picker } = this.props` is equivalent to `const picker = this.props.picker`

Comment: @Clarisa Your nested `map()` will return an array of arrays of type `<Tab>`. Is this what you want? Your question is a little vague, would you be able to elaborate, or provide more code?

Comment: true I guess it does @MattWay

Comment: @MattWay i want to display region in <Tab> so i tried to iterate the object first to get the item then access the region by mapping it, thats the only way i can think of

Comment: Im still not sure I understand. Your nested map given your data in your question will return all the regions twice. Do you want one set of possible regions? Do you want the regions of the first item only? You need to be more specific with what you need. Try providing an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `key` prop and iterate over a single item in picker:

```
  ...
         //display the region
          {picker[0].regions.map(item => {
            return <Tab key={item} label={item} />;
          })}
  ...
```

or if there is a possibility of having different regions in `male` and `female` you can aggregate them:

```
  ... 
        {picker.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          const depuded = curr.region.filter((i) => !acc.includes(i));
          return [...acc, ...depuded]
        }, []).map(item => (<Tab key={item} label={item} />))}
  ...
```